# C# filter fields are not working, but the code looks correct

Tags: c#, sql

My database has 3 filters  and I am trying to have them work together for a better search, but the code I am using says it is correct, but it is not working and often crashing the database with the error

> System.Data.SyntaxErrorException: 'Syntax error: Missing operand
> before '=' operator.'

here is my code

```
    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       

            DataView DV = new DataView(this.datasetocean.Water_Level);



        if (yearfilter.Text != null && yearfilter.Text.Length > 0 &&
            locationfilter.Text != null && locationfilter.Text.Length > 0 &&
            textBox1.Text != null && textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            if (yearfilter.Text.Length > 0 && int.TryParse(yearfilter.Text, out _))
            {

                DV.RowFilter = string.Format("location LIKE '%{0}%' AND waterlevel LIKE '%{1}%' AND year = '{2}'", yearfilter.Text, locationfilter.Text, textBox1.Text);
            };
        }
        else if (locationfilter.Text != null && locationfilter.Text.Length > 0 &&
                textBox1.Text != null && textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            DV.RowFilter = string.Format("location LIKE '%{0}%' AND waterlevel LIKE '%{1}%'", locationfilter.Text, textBox1.Text);
        }
        else if (yearfilter.Text != null && yearfilter.Text.Length > 0 &&
            locationfilter.Text != null && locationfilter.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            DV.RowFilter = string.Format("location LIKE '%{0}%' AND year = '{1}'", yearfilter.Text, locationfilter.Text);
        }
        else if (yearfilter.Text != null && yearfilter.Text.Length > 0 &&
            textBox1.Text != null && textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            DV.RowFilter = string.Format("year = '{0}' AND waterlevel LIKE = '{1}'",
            yearfilter.Text, textBox1.Text);
        }
        // Otherwise only include the name filter if the name filter is not empty
        else if (yearfilter.Text != null && yearfilter.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            DV.RowFilter = string.Format("year = '{0}'",
            yearfilter.Text);

        }
        else if (locationfilter.Text != null && locationfilter.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            DV.RowFilter = string.Format("location = '{0}'",
            locationfilter.Text);
        }
        else if (textBox1.Text != null && textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            DV.RowFilter = string.Format("waterlevel = '{0}'",
            textBox1.Text);
        };

        water_LevelDataGridView.DataSource = DV;


    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        DataView DV = new DataView(this.datasetocean.Water_Level);

        if (yearfilter.Text != null && yearfilter.Text.Length > 0 &&
            locationfilter.Text != null && locationfilter.Text.Length > 0 &&
            textBox1.Text != null && textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            if (yearfilter.Text.Length > 0 && int.TryParse(yearfilter.Text, out _))
            {

                DV.RowFilter = string.Format("location LIKE '%{0}%' AND waterlevel LIKE '%{1}%' AND year = '{2}'", yearfilter.Text, locationfilter.Text, textBox1.Text);
            };
        }
        else if (locationfilter.Text != null && locationfilter.Text.Length > 0 &&
                textBox1.Text != null && textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            DV.RowFilter = string.Format("Location LIKE '%{0}%' AND WaterLevel LIKE '%{1}%'", locationfilter.Text, textBox1.Text);
        }
        else if (yearfilter.Text != null && yearfilter.Text.Length > 0 &&
            locationfilter.Text != null && locationfilter.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            DV.RowFilter = string.Format("location LIKE '%{0}%' AND year = '{1}'", yearfilter.Text, locationfilter.Text);
        }
        else if (yearfilter.Text != null && yearfilter.Text.Length > 0 &&
            textBox1.Text != null && textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            DV.RowFilter = string.Format("year = '{0}' AND waterlevel LIKE = '{1}'",
            yearfilter.Text, textBox1.Text);
        }
        // Otherwise only include the name filter if the name filter is not empty
        else if (yearfilter.Text != null && yearfilter.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            DV.RowFilter = string.Format("year = '{0}'",
            yearfilter.Text);

        }
        else if (locationfilter.Text != null && locationfilter.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            DV.RowFilter = string.Format("location = '{0}'",
            locationfilter.Text);
        }
        else if (textBox1.Text != null && textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            DV.RowFilter = string.Format("waterlevel = '{0}'",
            textBox1.Text);
        };

        this.water_LevelDataGridView.DataSource = DV;


    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0 && int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out _))
        {
        DataView DV = new DataView(this.datasetocean.Water_Level);

            if (yearfilter.Text != null && yearfilter.Text.Length > 0 &&
                locationfilter.Text != null && locationfilter.Text.Length > 0 &&
                textBox1.Text != null && textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                if (yearfilter.Text.Length > 0 && int.TryParse(yearfilter.Text, out _))
                {

                    DV.RowFilter = string.Format("location LIKE '%{0}%' AND waterlevel LIKE '%{1}%' AND year = '{2}'", yearfilter.Text, locationfilter.Text, textBox1.Text);
                };
            }
            else if (locationfilter.Text != null && locationfilter.Text.Length > 0 &&
                    textBox1.Text != null && textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                DV.RowFilter = string.Format("location LIKE '%{0}%' AND waterlevel LIKE '%{1}%'", locationfilter.Text, textBox1.Text);
            }
            else if (yearfilter.Text != null && yearfilter.Text.Length > 0 &&
                locationfilter.Text != null && locationfilter.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                DV.RowFilter = string.Format("location LIKE '%{0}%' AND year = '{1}'", yearfilter.Text, locationfilter.Text);
            }
            else if (yearfilter.Text != null && yearfilter.Text.Length > 0 &&
                textBox1.Text != null && textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                DV.RowFilter = string.Format("year = '{0}' AND waterlevel LIKE = '{1}'",
                yearfilter.Text, textBox1.Text);
            }
            // Otherwise only include the name filter if the name filter is not empty
            else if (yearfilter.Text != null && yearfilter.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                DV.RowFilter = string.Format("year = '{0}'",
                yearfilter.Text);

            }
            else if (locationfilter.Text != null && locationfilter.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                DV.RowFilter = string.Format("location = '{0}'",
                locationfilter.Text);
            }
            else if (textBox1.Text != null && textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                DV.RowFilter = string.Format("waterlevel = '{0}'",
                textBox1.Text);
            };

            this.water_LevelDataGridView.DataSource = DV;
        }
    }
```

Comment: please do some refactor :)

Comment: Do not use string concatenation (including `string.Format`) to create an SQL command. Use parameterized statements. See [why it's a bad idea and how to fix it](//bobby-tables.com).

Comment: replace LIKE='{1}' to LIKE '{1}'

Answer (score 2):

You have a few lines that have

```
         DV.RowFilter = string.Format("year = '{0}' AND waterlevel LIKE = '{1}'",
```

The syntax for `LIKE` doesn't use an equals operator, and this is likely your issue.

This is more friendly advice, but you'll have a much easier time debugging your code if you try to simplify some of your conditions and replace repeating code with functions